# How to measure Remote Desktop Performance?

Tags: windows, performance, testing, benchmarking, remote-desktop

I am searching for a convenient but more important: *reproducible* way to measure the performance of a Remote Desktop Session. (Both bandwidth AND latency)

Does anyone have an idea how this can be done? I have thought about measuring the bandwidth to the server, but I am sure if this is a good indicator because it does not include latency and responsiveness.

I am happy about any ideas, hints or resources to read!

Comment: `Performance` of what actually?

Comment: Well, remote desktop sessions are sensitive to both latency and bandwidth: for a good experience you need both. So, sounds like a combination of ping times and bandwidth throughput is what you need.

Comment: @zerkms I think that is exactly the question :)

Comment: But which tools can I use for this? Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are performance counters for the "Terminal Service Session" on the destion computer you can use to see the maximum output frames and the compression ration.  The issue is that you need a controlled visual environment such as a looping full screen video to flood the pipe.  This will show you the maximum bandwidth by a single client across your pipe.